# Arduino button and led program

Tags: arduino-uno

"I am trying to make a program, where I have 6 modes controlled via a single push button, the problem is that after the SOS routine, the routine goes on forever and does not comply to a button push untill and unless i time it perfectly with the last S of the SOS. below is the program kindly explain how can I get out of the routine upon a push of a button.

secondly can this program be converted to .hexfile? for PIC12 micro controllers?
Regards,
Fawad"

```
// Uses button presses to switch an LED between off, dim, medium, high brightness & SOS.


// constants for this sketch
const int buttonPin = 2;       // pushbutton pin
const int led =  9;            // LED  pin
int dit = 500;                 //MORSE CODE dit
int dah = dit*3;               //MORSE CODE dah  
int blankTime = 100;            // GAP IN BETWEEN DIT AND DAH

// variables for this sketch
int ledMode = 1; // variable for recording button presses
int ledState = 6;
void setup() 
{
  // initialize the output pins:
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);

  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{ 
  // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH) 
  {     delay(100);
    // if it is, count a press
    ledMode = ledMode + 1;

    // if we've counted to an invalid mode 
    if (ledMode == 6)
    {delay(100);
      // reset to mode 1
      ledMode = 1;
    }
  }

  // Detect the current mode and set the LED appropriately
  if (ledMode == 1)
  {
    //Mode 1 - LED is off
    analogWrite(led, 0);
  }
  else if (ledMode == 2)
  {
    //Mode 2 - LED is dim
    analogWrite(led, 64);
    delay(100);
  }
  else if (ledMode == 3)
  {
    //Mode 3 - LED is medium
    analogWrite(led, 128);
delay(100);  
}
    else if(ledMode==4){

    //Mode 4 - LED is bright
    analogWrite(led, 255);
  delay(100);
}
else if(ledMode==5)
{
//Mode 5 -MORSE CODE
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait  
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait  
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait

  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dah);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dah);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dah);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait

  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);               // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime); }              // wait
  if(ledState==6){ 
return;}    
//return ;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `digitalRead` more frequently.

Add a button verifying routine to the middle and end of each "SOS" letter in order to clear the `ledMode`.

Like:

```
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);                // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);          // wait
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH) //READ
  {     delay(100);                   //DELAY
  ledMode = ledMode + 0;              //CLEAR
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);                // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);          // wait  
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH) //READ
  {     delay(100);                   //DELAY
  ledMode = ledMode + 0;              //CLEAR      
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(dit);                // wait
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(blankTime);          // wait
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH) //READ
  {     delay(100);                   //DELAY
  ledMode = ledMode + 0;              //CLEAR
```

Comment: No your suggestion is not working... can it be done by like case bases?